# Regex to match file types in Productivity Power Tools-plugin

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In the Visual Studio 2012 "Productivity Power Tools" plugin you can configure file tabs to be color coded based on regular expressions.
Im trying to match different file-types, like .less .cshtml, to have different colors but cant get it to work. Ive tried `.*\.cshtml` for example..
What regex should I use to target .less and cshtml?

Comment: Since regex is eager by default, maybe try `.*?\.cshtml`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Follow the next steps:

1. Go to *Tools -> Options*
2. Go to *Productivity Power Tools -> Custom Document Well -> General*
3. Make sure that you have checked the following 2 checkboxes:

   - *Color tabs by regular expression*
   - ***Regular expression colors have precedence over project colors***
4. Go to *Productivity Power Tools -> Custom Document Well -> Color Coding*
5. At the end of the list, in the new row, in the *RegEx/Project* column, add (this will match both file types):

   ```
   .*\.less|.*\.cshtml
   ```
6. Choose a color in the *Tab Color* column and click *OK* to save the settings

That's it.

Comment: Great, how do i change tab color also by project (i.e. if word business in project name have it x color)

Comment: For my use, I also needed Advanced -> "Use full document path for regular expression matching".

Comment: Yep, point 3 is the most important one, I didn't see that before, and I couldn't figure out why it wasn't enabling the colors! They hide these options in the dumbest places... why have an "advanced" section that deals mostly with colors, then put the one that enabled regex colors, in the general section!?!?!? Damn microsoft!